# Can I create missing keychain entries?

Tags: mail.app, password, keychain

The Mail app on a MacOSX 10.15 system keeps asking for entering the mail account's password. Gmail is working, the other accounts are not.

There is a keychain entry for the Gmail account. There are no keychain entries for the other email accounts.

I don't know why the keychain entries are missing (it is not my Mac). But my first idea is that the missing keychain entries should be re-created. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The keychain access app on macOS allows you to enter any keys you want. Perhaps that will let the Mail app realize it doesn’t need to prompt you.

It’s certainly where I would start.

- [Keychain Access User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/welcome/mac)

Comment: Thanks, @bmike. I've added a new password (in a new keychain). There was no information about what to enter as the password's "name", so I've taken the email address here. But there is no "magic" connection between the account in Mail and the keychain password happening. Mail still keeps asking to enter the password. Any further idea?